# Help? SPI communication slow

Tags: microcontroller, c, spi

I am using an [Intel Edison](http://download.intel.com/support/edison/sb/edisonarduino_hg_331191007.pdf) with Arduino Breakout Board to communicate via SPI to a [LS7366R Quadrature Encoder Buffer](http://cdn.usdigital.com/assets/general/LS7366R.pdf).  I am using the QEB as a timer: a pulse that enters the index will shift the counter register to an OTR register for reading.

My problem is with the speed of SPI communication from IE to QEB.  I am programming IE with a [mraa library](http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/index.html) to communicate via [SPI in C](http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/spi_8h.html).  According to a clock speed of 6.25 MHz, it should take 1.28 microseconds to transfer 1 byte.  Instead, it takes 60 microseconds.  I do not know why my SPI communication is slow.  I have already ensured that communication is working properly, albeit slow.

Proof: The following code takes on average .61 seconds to execute.  If I remove line 3, it takes on average .005 seconds to execute.

```
1. for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
2.     mraa_gpio_write(ss_o, 0);  // ss_o is slave select one
3.     mraa_spi_write(spi, 0x60); // transfer 1 byte via spi
4.     mraa_gpio_write(ss_o, 1);  // end transmission
5. }
```

My question: How can I speed up my spi communications?

I am using mraa version: v0.6.1

EDIT: After transmitting 5 bytes of data at a time, I found that the initialization may be taking a long time.  Replacing line 3 above with...

```
3.    mraa_spi_write_buf(spi, write_buf, 5);
```

... results in .65 seconds, a minute increase of time for 5 times the data sent.  I am not an expert on parsing libraries, so can anyone help me find the bottleneck in the mraa spi library?  I want to see if I can edit it to speed up the SPI calls.

EDIT: CLARIFICATION: I am intending to use the counter as a timer; every time a pulse comes in I want to know when it came in.  Therefore, I need fast repeated reads of the OTR register.

EDIT: added full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "mraa.h"

int i = 0;
mraa spi_context spi;
mraa_gpio_context ss_o;  // ss_o is slave select one
clock_t start, end;

int main(void) {
    spi = mraa_spi_init(0);
    mraa_spi_frequency(spi, 6250000); // Set frequency to 6.25 MHz
    mraa_spi_mode(spi, 0);
    ss_o = mraa_gpio_init(10);  // ss_o is pin 10)
    mraa_gpio_dir(ss_o, MRAA_GPIO_OUT);
    mraa_gpio_use_mmaped(ss_o, 1);
    mraa_gpio_write(ss_o, 1);

    // Initialize counters
    mraa_gpio_write(ss_o, 0); // Begin SPI conversation
    mraa_spi_write(spi, 0x90);
    mraa_spi_write(spi, 0x1);
    mraa_gpio_write(ss_o, 1); // Terminate SPI conversation

    mraa_gpio_write(ss_o, 0); // Begin SPI conversation
    mraa_spi_write(spi, 0x88);
    mraa_spi_write(spi, 0x30);
    mraa_gpio_write(ss_o, 1); // Terminate SPI conversation

    start = clock();  // For measuring time
    for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        mraa_gpio_write(ss_o, 0);  // ss_o is slave select one
        mraa_spi_write(spi, 0x60); // transfer 1 byte via spi
        mraa_gpio_write(ss_o, 1);  // end transmission
    }
    end = clock();
    double diff = (double)(end - start) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("Time elapsed: %f\n", diff);

}
```

Comment: What is the data rate?

Comment: where is the piece that initializes SPI peripheral?

Comment: I have omitted the initialization code.  I can add that.

Comment: I'd suggest to try mraa_spi_write_buf, doing a large enough block transfer and comparing the results. Possibly the time to setup the SPI port over and over to transfer each byte is eating a lot of time.

Comment: @fceconel I will try that and post results, thanks!

Comment: @fceconel I found that the time to set up the SPI port over and over *is* eating a lot of time.  I added the results to my post.  Would you be able to help me with this?

Comment: I'm afraid it'll be hard to circumvent the performance bottleneck; it may be due to the fact that there's a system call to be made (ioctl), which for many reasons is a time-consuming operation, or something in the driver code itself. You'd probably need to interface directly to the SPI port (and maybe this needs to be done in a device driver), which is no trivial task; I have no experience with Yocto or the SPI drivers for the Edison, so I don't think I can offer much further help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,,,,there is no need to select same slave and end transmission for every count,,,,you can end it after all 10000 counts are finished

```
  mraa_gpio_write(ss_o, 0);  // ss_o is slave select one  
  for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
    {
        mraa_spi_write(spi, 0x60); // transfer 1 byte via spi    
    }
mraa_gpio_write(ss_o, 1);  // end transmission
```

hope this helps